What's difference between (TPU) Transaction Processing Unit and (TVU) Transaction Validation Unit?
When reading docs about Solana validator, I stumbled upon these terms, and as far as I understand, both of them are the same hardware, but TPU is when it works in a leader mode, and TVU - when it works in a validator mode.
Still, I don't get what is the functional difference between them, and why give them a different name.

Although they are both processing transactions, everything else they do is very different! It might be most instructive to simply look at what each one requires in the source code.
For the TPU, let's look at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/f121f73ce3461924fc37c022ecb40ac07f24b590/core/src/tpu.rs#L64. When a validator is leader, and using the TPU, it needs to:

fetch transactions
verify their signatures
record transaction results directly into the bank
create and sign "shreds" from transactions and broadcast the block

For the TVU, let's look at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/f121f73ce3461924fc37c022ecb40ac07f24b590/core/src/tvu.rs#L63. When a validator is validating, and using the TVU, it will:

receive and dedupe shreds
verify shred signatures
retransmit shreds to downstream nodes through Turbine
replay the transactions into the appropriate bank (rather than the latest bank)
vote on the block

So while there are some similarities, the rest is very different!

Thanks for explaining to me!
